# Email server - Sending problem

Tags: email-server

Recently i set up a M Daemon email server on a windows 2003 standard server. everything seems right. But when i configure the email client with the email server host name to send out emails, the email client is not sending the email but returns with socket error: 10060. what would be the problem. Have to do any setting anywhere..? I assume that the email client config has no problem.. any help is greatly needed...

Answer (score 1):

"socket error: 10060" there is probably another application on the system utilizing port 25. Good chance it may be IIS, since it has a SMTP component as well - which can be disabled in this case.

Comment: so should i diable to iis, also if i suppose to run a website fromthis server, then what should I do...?

Comment: I now checked & found that the IIS is not running... so what else would be the reason...

Comment: Try "telnet 127.0.0.1 25" (without the quotes) at the command prompt to see what actually answers. Most typical SMTP host/servers will display a SMTP banner which may provide clues as to its identity.

Comment: the output is like this:

Comment: 220 tradevisionltd.com ESMTP MDaemon FREE 12.0.3; Mon, 27 Jun 2011 16:58:39 +080
0

Comment: "email client is not sending the email but returns with socket error: 10060" The tests/troubleshooting steps are being conducted on the client exhibiting the error situation?

Comment: Also Strangely this server does not respond for ping request from outside. Also web mail URL can not be opened thru Internet explorer, but Firefox & chrom can able to open the web mail URL... So strange

Comment: Can you telnet to the server from the problematic client on port 25? If so, what is the output result? How about ping from the problematic client to the server as well as the different web browsers? What are the IP settings/configurations of the server and problematic client?

Comment: From the problematic client: 1.unable to connect to the host... the result is: "C:\>telnet mail8.tradevisionltd.com 25
Connecting To mail8.tradevisionltd.com...Could not open connection to the host,
on port 25: Connect failed "

2. unable to ping also from this client also as well as from other systems. The server & the client are at different locations & not in the same location. The client has the dynamic IP setting, the server has the fixed ip settings

Comment: Please provide the actual IP configuration of both the server and non working client(s).